# Google Maps Android V2 application crashing

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on a project that includes location detection using the GPS so I found this code that included a working .apk file but when I tried to compile it and run it, it always crashes. The application crashes when I try opening it in an emulator or on a Samsung S4 mobile. 
N.B.
I've chosen the correct target which is API 17 and downloaded Google play services and included it in the library of the project.

Here is the code if anyone can help

**Manifest file**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDciL7-T3BphxGv2q-A77vNrcyJQ_sTrgI"/>
    <activity
        android:name="info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package info.tekguc.umut.googlemapsmapsandroidv2;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
    Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title(
            "My Office"));

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
 }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
12-25 17:30:32.450: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 15% free 7250K/8524K, paused 487ms, total 487ms
12-25 17:30:32.940: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 253K, 18% free 6999K/8524K, paused 463ms, total 465ms
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286): Failure sending broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000010 (has extras) }
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286): android.os.DeadObjectException
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:124)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.performReceiveLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:376)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.deliverToRegisteredReceiverLocked(BroadcastQueue.java:439)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue.processNextBroadcast(BroadcastQueue.java:487)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue$1.handleMessage(BroadcastQueue.java:140)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 17:30:32.950: W/BroadcastQueue(286):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1480)
12-25 17:30:34.300: I/ActivityManager(286): Start proc com.google.process.gapps for content provider com.google.android.gsf/.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider: pid=518 uid=10019 gids={50019, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 1006, 2001, 3006}
12-25 17:30:34.350: W/ActivityManager(286): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40f692c8 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
12-25 17:30:34.380: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 6% free 2403K/2552K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 96ms
12-25 17:30:34.410: W/ActivityManager(286): Timeout executing service: ServiceRecord{40fa9d20 u0 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME}
12-25 17:30:34.480: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 2404K/2552K, paused 4ms+14ms, total 96ms
12-25 17:30:34.540: I/Choreographer(405): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-25 17:30:34.590: D/dalvikvm(37): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 6% free 2404K/2552K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 105ms
12-25 17:30:34.720: E/UserHistoryDictionary(378): when loading: file not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin/files/UserHistoryDictionary.en_US.dict: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-25 17:30:34.840: E/Trace(501): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-25 17:30:34.890: D/DebugService(390): DebugService DebugService:
12-25 17:30:34.890: D/TelephonyDebugService(390): TelephonyDebugService()
12-25 17:30:35.440: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 378 SIG: 3
12-25 17:30:35.440: I/dalvikvm(378): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-25 17:30:35.440: D/dalvikvm(390): GC_CONCURRENT freed 318K, 14% free 2691K/3124K, paused 4ms+168ms, total 591ms
12-25 17:30:35.640: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 286 SIG: 3
12-25 17:30:35.640: I/dalvikvm(286): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-25 17:30:35.970: D/dalvikvm(378): GC_CONCURRENT freed 239K, 13% free 2561K/2912K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 1274ms
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:412)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:428)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:979)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionaryGetter.loadFallbackResource(BinaryDictionaryGetter.java:183)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.BinaryDictionaryGetter.getDictionaryFiles(BinaryDictionaryGetter.java:456)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryFactory.createMainDictionaryFromManager(DictionaryFactory.java:57)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.DictionaryFactory.createMainDictionaryFromManager(DictionaryFactory.java:87)
12-25 17:30:36.021: E/StrictMode(378):  at com.android.inputmethod.latin.Suggest$1.run(Suggest.java:108)
12-25 17:30:36.030: I/dalvikvm(378): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-25 17:30:37.332: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 501 SIG: 3
12-25 17:30:37.332: I/dalvikvm(501): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-25 17:30:37.420: I/dalvikvm(286): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-25 17:30:37.420: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 390 SIG: 3
12-25 17:30:37.420: I/dalvikvm(390): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-25 17:30:38.040: I/dalvikvm(501): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-25 17:30:38.230: E/Trace(518): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-25 17:30:38.810: I/dalvikvm(390): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-25 17:30:39.083: W/Settings(390): Setting auto_time_zone has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
12-25 17:30:39.410: D/dalvikvm(390): GC_CONCURRENT freed 60K, 14% free 2704K/3124K, paused 70ms+103ms, total 726ms
12-25 17:30:39.860: W/WindowManager(286): Window freeze timeout expired.
12-25 17:30:39.860: W/WindowManager(286): Force clearing orientation change: Window{41084730 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
12-25 17:30:39.962: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-25 17:30:40.870: I/Choreographer(405): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-25 17:30:42.290: E/BluetoothAdapter(286): Bluetooth binder is null
12-25 17:30:42.310: E/BluetoothAdapter(286): Bluetooth binder is null
12-25 17:30:42.310: V/WiredAccessoryManager(286): init()
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: E/SoundPool(286): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.430: W/AudioService(286): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-25 17:30:42.450: W/AudioService(286): loadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
12-25 17:30:42.560: I/Choreographer(405): Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-25 17:30:42.660: I/ActivityManager(286): Start proc com.android.music for broadcast com.android.music/.MediaButtonIntentReceiver: pid=543 uid=10029 gids={50029, 3003, 1015, 1028}
12-25 17:30:43.510: D/CAT(390): CatService: Running CAT service. STK app installed:false
12-25 17:30:43.510: D/CAT(390): CatService: NEW sInstance
12-25 17:30:43.730: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_EXPLICIT freed 565K, 14% free 7366K/8524K, paused 673ms+462ms, total 2446ms
12-25 17:30:43.750: I/dalvikvm(543): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 9...
12-25 17:30:44.780: E/Trace(543): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-25 17:30:45.049: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 186K, 8% free 3648K/3948K, paused 546ms, total 569ms
12-25 17:30:45.190: I/dalvikvm-heap(405): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.549MB for 921616-byte allocation
12-25 17:30:45.610: I/Process(286): Sending signal. PID: 405 SIG: 3
12-25 17:30:45.610: I/dalvikvm(405): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): ANR in com.android.inputmethod.latin
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): Reason: Executing service com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): Load: 5.63 / 2.02 / 0.73
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): CPU usage from 0ms to 11459ms later:
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   35% 36/surfaceflinger: 32% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 2 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   25% 286/system_server: 17% user + 7.4% kernel / faults: 972 minor 1 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   8.8% 390/com.android.phone: 5.6% user + 3.2% kernel / faults: 605 minor 5 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   7.2% 405/com.android.launcher: 4.8% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 913 minor 3 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   6.6% 86/bootanimation: 5.6% user + 1% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   3.9% 518/zygote: 0.9% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 2601 minor 19 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   2% 441/android.process.acore: 1.5% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 228 minor 1 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   1.6% 501/com.android.systemui: 0.8% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 719 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   0.8% 378/zygote: 0.5% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 446 minor 1 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   0% 30/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   0% 35/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   0.1% 1//init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):  +0% 543/com.android.music: 0% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): 100% TOTAL: 76% user + 23% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): CPU usage from 9332ms to 10684ms later:
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   40% 36/surfaceflinger: 37% user + 3.2% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     37% 67/SurfaceFlinger: 35% user + 1.6% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 84/EventThread: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 85/Binder_1: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 238/Binder_2: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   19% 286/system_server: 11% user + 7.8% kernel / faults: 47 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     8.7% 303/ActivityManager: 5.2% user + 3.5% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     2.6% 293/Compiler: 1.7% user + 0.8% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     1.7% 470/Binder_7: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 286/system_server: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 423/Binder_4: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 439/Binder_6: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.8% 471/Binder_8: 0.8% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   12% 405/com.android.launcher: 8.1% user + 4.5% kernel / faults: 274 minor 1 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     7.2% 405/ndroid.launcher: 3.6% user + 3.6% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     2.7% 407/GC: 1.8% user + 0.9% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.9% 412/Compiler: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   10% 543/com.android.music: 3.4% user + 6.8% kernel / faults: 714 minor 1 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     11% 543/re-initialized>: 4.2% user + 7.6% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   8% 86/bootanimation: 7.1% user + 0.8% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     7.1% 103/BootAnimation: 6.2% user + 0.8% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   4.5% 390/com.android.phone: 2.7% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 33 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     6.3% 390/m.android.phone: 3.6% user + 2.7% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.9% 392/GC: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     0.9% 401/Compiler: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   4.8% 518/com.google.process.gapps: 1.9% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 250 minor 6 major
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):     8.6% 518/e.process.gapps: 2.8% user + 5.7% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286):   0.7% 1//init: 0.7% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
12-25 17:30:46.520: E/ActivityManager(286): 100% TOTAL: 74% user + 25% kernel
12-25 17:30:46.839: I/FusedLocation(474): engine started (com.android.location.fused)
12-25 17:30:47.470: I/dalvikvm(405): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-25 17:30:47.480: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_CONCURRENT freed 9K, 7% free 4538K/4852K, paused 7ms+1868ms, total 2294ms
12-25 17:30:47.490: D/dalvikvm(405): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 3ms
12-25 17:30:47.600: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 556K, 18% free 7048K/8524K, paused 976ms, total 978ms
12-25 17:30:47.700: W/ActivityManager(286): Killing ProcessRecord{40f90870 378:com.android.inputmethod.latin/u0a10022}: background ANR
12-25 17:30:47.720: I/ActivityManager(286): Process com.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 378) has died.
12-25 17:30:47.720: W/ActivityManager(286): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME in 5000ms
12-25 17:30:47.750: D/CAT(390): CatService: SIM ready. Reporting STK service running now...
12-25 17:30:47.920: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 4539K/4852K, paused 407ms, total 428ms
12-25 17:30:48.092: I/dalvikvm-heap(405): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.419MB for 921616-byte allocation
12-25 17:30:48.480: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 5439K/5756K, paused 6ms+78ms, total 388ms
12-25 17:30:48.480: D/dalvikvm(405): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 259ms
12-25 17:30:48.630: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 5440K/5756K, paused 132ms, total 146ms
12-25 17:30:48.659: I/dalvikvm-heap(405): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.299MB for 921616-byte allocation
12-25 17:30:48.730: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 252K, 18% free 7025K/8524K, paused 752ms, total 756ms
12-25 17:30:49.160: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 6340K/6660K, paused 27ms+5ms, total 509ms
12-25 17:30:49.160: D/dalvikvm(405): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 346ms
12-25 17:30:49.510: D/MccTable(390): updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=310, mnc=260
12-25 17:30:49.510: D/TelephonyManager(390): getLteOnCdmaMode=0 curVal=-1 product_type='' lteOnCdmaProductType=''
12-25 17:30:49.510: D/MccTable(390): locale set to en_us
12-25 17:30:49.510: D/MccTable(390): WIFI_COUNTRY_CODE set to us
12-25 17:30:49.691: I/WifiService(286): WifiService trying to set country code to us with persist set to true
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @MD here's the logcat

Comment: @CommonsWare Here's the logcat

Comment: There is no Java stack trace in that LogCat that would pertain to your crash. Hence, either you are not crashing, or you did not capture the stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all code that references your GoogleMap to onStart() or onResume(). The map in a map fragment isn't instantiated until after the fragment has gone through onCreateView ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMap%28%29)).  So, move the following to onStart():

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
if(mMap != null) {
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
    Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title(
        "My Office"));
}
```

Also, the null check is necessary because the map will be null if google play services aren't installed, or the map isn't available for some other reason.